# Get the Current QueryPerfromanceCounter Value in Debugger

Tags: windows, debugging, time, windbg, performancecounter

Is there a way to get the current value of [QueryPerformanceCounter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/profileapi/nf-profileapi-queryperformancecounter) while in the debugger? We use QPC in our code for all time values, but without the "current" time we have no way to calculate the time delta for these values.

Answer (score 0):

I am Not sure what you are looking for ?
if you want to Call QueryPerformanceCounter from an extension you can use the code below compile an extension and bang it out

```
#include <engextcpp.cpp>
class EXT_CLASS : public ExtExtension
{
public:
    EXT_COMMAND_METHOD(qpc);
};
EXT_DECLARE_GLOBALS();
EXT_COMMAND(qpc,"","")
{
    LARGE_INTEGER perfcount  = {0};
    BOOL res = QueryPerformanceCounter(&perfcount);
    if(res) {
        Out("perfcounter is %I64X\n",perfcount.QuadPart);
    }
}
```

compiled and linked with as x64 from dev cmd prompt

```
cl /LD /nologo /W4 /Ox  /Zi /EHsc /I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\inc" %1.cpp /link /EXPORT:DebugExtensionInitialize /Export:%1 /Export:help /RELEASE
```

usage

```
.load .\qpc.dll
.chain 
Extension DLL chain:
    .\qpc.dll: API 1.0.0, built Wed Feb  2 02:56:14 2022
        [path: F:\src\wdbgexts\qpc\qpc.dll]
0:000> !qpc
perfcounter is 6A0832C7711
0:000> !qpc
perfcounter is 6A0841BE77B
0:000> !qpc
perfcounter is 6A084A392A8
0:000>
```

if opening a shell is acceptable then you can also use powershell stopwatch

```
0:000> !qpc;.shell  -ci "$$" "cmd /k powershell -Command 'perfcounter is {0:X}' -f [system.diagnostics.stopwatch]::GetTimestamp()"
perfcounter is 3E79CEF8BE
perfcounter is 3E79F0D3F7

C:\WINDOWS\system32>.shell: Process exited
0:000>
```

Comment: I need to know the value of qpc in the dump file I am analyzing, not the current running machine. Sorry if that was unclear.

Comment: the !wmitrace extension will dump the last buffer of LOGGER ID 2 if your application uses traces and they may contain the counters .